# All chrome extensions gone after update, is there any way to restore, check a log to see what happened, or revert the update?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, updates, automatic-update, recovery

I just started using a computer I haven't been using for a while (4 months approximately).  I actually restored it from hibernation, I guess I never shut it down the last time I used it, and chrome was still open (still on an old version with the trapezoid tabs at the top).  I used it for a bit, then closed everything down and did a restart.

Upon reopening chrome, after browsing for a while I realised all my extensions were gone.

Apart from the inconvenience of having to find all the extensions I previously had and re-install them, the real problem is that one of the extensions was a session manager, which I'd use to store groups of windows as bookmarks.  Now that's gone, I appear to have lost all these bookmarks.

So is there any way to get this data back, or revert this update, or at least see a log file to find out what has happened, and why?

Comment: Within the Chrome user profile directory is the session extension data gone.  Update your question with this relevant information necessary to answer your question

Comment: Are you sure they are really uninstalled in chrome or just disabled?